# Any software to resume a copy of a huge file when there is network disconnection?

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, file-transfer

I would like to know if there is a software for Windows which allows me to copy a huge file from a remote desktop network to my local PC, and if this copy gets interrupted, I would like to resume the copy process. I have tried **Teracopy** but its `Resume` feature does not work when network connection gets interrupted.

This is the scenario:

- I connect to a remote computer using **Remote desktop**, sharing a local drive, so the remote computer can see my shared drive (such as U:)
- On the remote computer I want to copy the remote file to the shared drive (U:).
- Local computer has Windows 8, remote computer has Windows 2003
- There is no internet connection available in remote computer

The problem:

- connection is really slow from remote computer and when there is a disconnection, I cannot resume the copy process

is there a software which offers a **resume** feature to avoid copying the whole file again from scratch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to resume download from network drive if it gets disconnected?](http://superuser.com/questions/492145/possible-to-resume-download-from-network-drive-if-it-gets-disconnected), [How to continue file transfer to LAN target on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/453157/how-to-continue-file-transfer-to-lan-target-on-windows), [Copy Files With Partial Resume Support? (Win/Cygwin)](http://superuser.com/questions/97181/copy-files-with-partial-resume-support-win-cygwin)

Comment: [Why every OS still can't resume file transferring?](http://superuser.com/questions/109839/why-every-os-still-cant-resume-file-transferring)

Comment: I am trying CopyFile to check if it resumes the copy http://sourceforge.net/projects/copyfile/ If it does not work I will try those articles

Comment: You could also run an FTP server and use a client that supports resume. Another way, which I often use for remote sites with an unreliable internet connection, is to use my DropBox account (paid accounts have a higher size limit). Install DropBox client on remote machine, create a free account for that machine and share a folder with it from your main account, drop file in shared folder, then you can just forget about it. Eventually, it will be copied (and DropBox supports resume). Check back in a few minutes / hours. I like this way a lot because it's completely passive.

Comment: Oh and there's also [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp), an rsync wrapper for Windows. This implicitly supports resume. This would integrate into your currently described workflow more smoothly than DropBox.

Comment: A quirky idea that got me out of a similar situation, is creating a private torrent and seed (only to yourself) from the remote machine to the local one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that CopyFile works as expected. It does not show the estimated time left but shows copy progress in percentage.

It also has an input box for repeating / resuming the copy as many times as you want.

Select source, target, select the file, click Add then Start.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/copyfile/